# What are some interesting tricks to minimize image usage in a website?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm big on reducing the use of images in web pages wherever possible, like CSS gradients, transparency, rounded corners, etc. More functionality is becoming possible with the growth of HTML5 and CSS3. What are some good tricks to know?

Comment: Is the goal to decrease the number of connections needed or to minimize the actual size transferred?

Comment: Your question should be more specific: Are you attempting to apply a specific technique and encountering difficulty? Have you tried (and failed) to replicate a particular graphic in CSS? We can help with these things.

Answer (score 3):

Use images when they actually represent a picture, and use CSS when it's for graphics.

Answer (score 0):

check the power of css3 on the following link http://css3.mikeplate.com/

Answer (score 0):

Here are some good examples of drawing shapes using CSS.

http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/